# How to get geometric shapes with specified sizes?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to get geometric shapes in TikZ whose size is independent of any text I may have in them. Consider this MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\tikzset{trap/.style={shape=trapezium,draw=black,minimum width=1.0cm,
  minimum height=1.0cm,shape border uses incircle}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{trapezium stretches=true}
\node[trap=green] (trap) at (-1,0) {};
\node[trap=green] (trap) at (1,0) {A};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

It produces the following:

[image]

(The top being cut off has nothing to do with TikZ, but with Apple's Preview when I export ...)

How can I get the size to be independent of any text that may be in the shape?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way of getting the size independent of the text is to place the text as a label. For your convenience I slightly redefined `trap` such that the first argument really gets used and the second argument is the above-mentioned label. Needless to say that if the text gets too wide, it will overshoot. (And preview does not cut the picture on my Mac.)

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\tikzset{trap/.style 2 args={shape=trapezium,draw=black,minimum width=1.0cm,draw=#1,label=center:#2,
  minimum height=1.0cm,shape border uses incircle,}} % text width=0pt,text height=1em,align=flush center
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{trapezium stretches=true}
\node[trap={green}{}] (trap) at (-1,0) {};
\node[trap={green}{A}] (trap) at (1,0) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Not sure what is going on with Preview...

Answer (score 1):

You could use also `text width=width("<put here your larger text>")` to have all the nodes with the text width of the lager text.

I also put `#1` after `draw=` in the definition of your style, as you're using that parameter.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\tikzset{trap/.style={shape=trapezium,draw=#1,minimum width=1.0cm,
  minimum height=1.0cm,shape border uses incircle,
  text width=width("A"),%put here the larger text
  text centered}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{trapezium stretches=true}
\node[trap=green] (trap) at (-1,0) {};
\node[trap=green] (trap1) at (1,0) {A};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]